# И снова о "лопаньи"

Tags: этимология

Тут задавали вопрос о слове "лопать" в значении "сдувать что-то надутое". С этим все понятно, но мне стало интересно, почему слово "лопать" еще употребляют с ироничного обозначения процесса еды? Например: "Он слопал оба моих пирожных!"
Вроде бы поглощение пищи ничем не похоже на прокалывание пузырей, и тем не менее.
И еще, подскажите, пожалуйста, как обозвать слово "лопать": жаргон, сленг, словечко - не знаю адекватного термина для него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вульгаризм, жаргонизм - просторечная лексика. Словари молодёжного жаргона его тоже включают как стилистически сниженный синоним слов и выражений лит. языка с  резкой оценочностью, экспрессивностью. Ср.:  кушать – жрать, лопать, трескать; лицо – харя, морда, рожа, рыло; плохой человек – сволочь, скотина, гад, подлец и т.д.

На прокалывание пузырей, конечно, поглощение пищи не похоже, но быстрое и жадное поглощение пищи звуками сопровождается, не зря говорят "Аж за ушами трещит", вот вам и "трескает", а иногда чавканье похоже и на звук чего-то лопающегося. Русский народ наблюдателен, разговорная речь  экспрессивна и точна.

Answer (score 1):

Лопать - грубо-простор. (по словарю ненормативной лексики) - есть, пить (обыкновенно много, жадно). Лопать, трескать - слова звукоподражательные, сравнить: лепетать.